# XML-part wont map to String using SOAPBinding

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, soap, binding

Consider the following Interface:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(Style=SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface MySoapBinderWS extends Remote {

  @WebMethod
  public String workPlease(@WebParam(name="arg1")String arg1, @WebParam(name="xml")String xml);
}
```

And the following implementation:

```
public class MySoapBinderWSBean implements MySoapBinderWS {
    public String workPlease(String arg1, String xml){
        System.out.println("arg1: " + arg1);
        System.out.println("xml:  " + xml);
        return "Length of xml: " + xml.length(); //This will return 0
    }
}
```

This is the SOAP request that I use to test my service:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="....">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ws:workPlease>
      <arg1>hellooo</arg1>
      <xml><someTag>helooo</someTag></xml>
    </ws:workPlease>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The problem I have is that the text inside the "xml" tag wont map to the String. It will always show an empty String and return 0. While the text inside the "arg1" tag maps/binds correctly.
I also noticed that it works if I change from

```
<someTag>helooo</someTag>
```

to

```
&lt;someTag&gt;helooo&lt;/someTag&gt;
```

But this is not an option for me! Any suggestions!? :)

Comment: Your webmethod defines the <xml> element as a string, but the content of the <xml> element in the test message is XML. Hence your problem. You need to 'XML escape' the text if it contains any XML characters (like < or >). And that's exactly what the 2nd example string you provided is => The XML escaped version of the <someTag>...</someTag>. Assuming you'll use an XML/SOAP api to generate the messages; what is the 'not an option' about?

Comment: There are a lot of other parts of our organization, that are using the same API/function/services, so I'm not in a position of telling all the others to change it. So the question is rather, how do I do the escaping on the server side?

Comment: Have a look at a message send by others to the same service when it's on the wire. You'll see the content of the XML parameter being 'XML escaped' when 'on the wire'. The bottom one is what you need. Your test message example is 'incorrect'.